# Collaborative parameter not working on Foursquare list add method?

Tags: ruby, api, foursquare

When trying to create a new list via api

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/add

collaborative is always set to false, ignoring any true, "true", 1...

Anybody with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed this is really a bug on add list endpoint, because if you update the list you just created, and set collaborative to true, it works :)